# Getting data by datetime interval from SQL Server with EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a stock table containing the values of a currency each milisecond approximately.
This causes the table to have several milions of rows (3 mil per month) and I can't figure out how to query more than 2 months without getting Out of Memory Exception.

The point is that I don't need each row but only the rows separated by a minutes interval (let's say 1 minute, 5 minutes, etc). I could reduce to reasonable number of rows if i could do this with a query.

At moment I'm loading all rows in a List then

```
var resultTicks = new List<Tick> { ticks.First() };

for (var i = 1; i < ticks.Count(); i++)
{
    if (ticks[i].Data > resultTicks.Last().Data.AddMinutes(minutesInterval))
    resultTicks.Add(ticks[i]);
}
```

This is the best solution that i came with but is far by being performance

Comment: is EF really a good idea for this kind of thing? I would have though you would use some special index or datawarehouse

Comment: Wow, do you really need all those data? Shouldn't you extract/aggregate before you load them into your system? I don't think any solution will perform well with this kind of numbers, although a memory-base solution with EF will be one of the worst. A table-valued function is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of to improve your performance.

**Option 1:**

You'll want to filter your results down as far as you can, otherwise you'll force your database to grind generating these results.

```
var resultTicks = ticks.GroupBy(t => t.Data.Year + "-" + t.Data.Month + "-" + t.Data.Day + " " + t.Data.Hour + ":" + t.Data.Minute)
    .Select(t => new
        {
            Group = t.Key,
            FirstRecord = t.FirstOrDefault()
        })
    .ToList();
```

**Option 2:**

Create a view to allow optimized queries.  Add this view to Entity Framework like you would a normal table and still filter as much as you can to reduce the load on your database.

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Ticks T
(
    SELECT
        Currency,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), Data, 121) AS DateGroup,
        MIN(Data) AS MinData
    FROM dbo.Ticks
    GROUP BY Currency, CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), Data, 121)
) TG ON TG.Currency = T.Currency
    AND TG.MinData = T.Data;
```

**Option 3:**

At the beginning or end of each minute, store the expected result into a summary table.  This will prevent your data intensive filters and groups.